# Should jQuery .on() work on mobile (iPhone Safari)?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a', function() {
    //bla
});
```

and what happens is that the whole `#container` gets highlighted by the click and not the `a` and the event doesn't work.
 Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile, or just the jQuery core.

Comment: More than likely it isn't related to jquery. Try giving the anchor tag an onclick and remove the jquery to confirm.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am having trouble binding to dynamically generated elements also. Works in my browser, but not my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('#container a').on('click', function() {
    //bla
});
```

You do have a powerful selector engine in jQuery, why not use it?

Comment: Because if the `a` is dynamically generated that method doesn't work.